# Versioning rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, versioning

I was trying to find a way to manage different versions for my rails API.
Different routing is not a problem, the problem begins when i'm changing the models and the database (Postgres) between different versions. What is the best practice for managing different versions in rails API ? Thanks guys

Edit: **Example** -the problem arrives when i'm changing one of the model from V1 to V2. Lets say that at V1 i has a model called 'Product' that I accidently saved the 'price' property in string instead of integer, at V2 i saw the problem and made a migration that fixs the problem. The fix made a new problem,now V1 API is broken because is trying to take string from integer column

Comment: Are you trying to maintain some level of backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 2):

What I like to do is create different endpoint

1)  set your routes

```
namespace :api do

  namespace :v1 do
    resources :...
  end

  namespace :v2 do
    resources :...
  end

end
```

Now that you have your end points you can create your controllers
The way I like to  do it is

```
#app/controller/api_controller.rb
class ApiController < ActionController::Base

  layout false
  ...

end
```

Now you have a folder in your controller folder for each version

app/controllers/api/v1
app/controllers/api/v2

Now in each your expose what your need

```
class Api::V1::MooController < ApiController

end
```

**update**

You can not remove the string value of **price** but you have to create a new field call **int_price**. That way api v1 can still properly respond to the string price

Now you would also need a method that would populate the int_price when ever the string price gets updated

**note**

I don't think that your should have a new endpoint just to change a price from string to an integer you could just write a method `if string` convert to integer

I hope that this helps

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you. secondly i added to my question much more details about the problem that I'm facing. I would you like you read this please

Comment: Stripe seems to have a pretty interesting approach: https://stripe.com/blog/api-versioning